# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Express.js, update empties /uploads folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I update my my app `eb push`, my `/uploads` directory gets cleared. I'm using this folder to store images. I thought maybe it had to do with git and so I added this folder to the `.gitignore`, but it still clears the folder on update. Why does this happen? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just found the answer I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066972/pushing-to-elastic-beanstalk-removes-files-created-on-servers). Quite simply, I need to use cloud storage, like S3.